# Sqlite query to get list of next available characters after the matching search keyword

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

How to query sqlite database to get list of next available characters after the search keyword in a string field.
for example, if the search keyword is ’and’

and let the strings be a list of names like :

1. And**y** Xyz
2. And**r**ew Xyz
3. Xyz And**o**n
4. Xyz Mirand**a**

then i should get the characters [y,r,o,a].

I tried the query with **substr(names,1,1)**, but substr needs to specify the start index which will be different in each strings. Is it possible to fetch these characters using sqlite query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `substr()` and `instr()`:

```
select 
substr(names, instr(lower(names), lower('and')) + length('and'), 1) nextchar 
from tablename
where 
  names like '%' || 'and' || '_%'
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7KLhoGq4facEpHm8nvy2hp/2)
You can replace `'and'` with any string you wish in the above query.

Answer (score 1):

You could utilise the **[instr](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#instr)** function to ascertain the start of the substr e.g. :-

```
SELECT *, substr(names,instr(lower(names),'and') + length('and'),1) AS onechar
FROM mytable WHERE names LIKE ('%and%');
```

A working example :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (names TEXT);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES('Andy Xyz'),('Andrew Xyz'),
('Xyz Andon'),('Xyz Miranda');
SELECT *, substr(names,instr(lower(names),'and') + length('and'),1) AS onechar FROM mytable WHERE names LIKE ('%and%');
```

This results in :-

[image]

as per your expected results.